# Taskscheduler class not working in XP

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

Hi I have a program that schedules task. While this runs fine on Windows7 machine, it throws an error on XP.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using TaskScheduler;

namespace MyTaskScheduler
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string STR_DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";
                string taskName = "MyTask";
                string taskFolder = "MyTaskFolder";

                Console.WriteLine("Creating task");
                ITaskService taskScheduler = new TaskSchedulerClass();
                taskScheduler.Connect(null, null, null, null);

                ITaskFolder rootFolder = taskScheduler.GetFolder(@"\");
                bool _found = false;
                foreach (ITaskFolder fol in rootFolder.GetFolders(0))
                {
                    if (fol.Name == taskFolder)
                        _found = true;
                }
                if (!_found)
                    rootFolder.CreateFolder(taskFolder, null);
                ITaskFolder folder = rootFolder.GetFolder("\\" + taskFolder);

                _found = false;
                foreach (IRegisteredTask tsk in folder.GetTasks(0))
                {
                    if (tsk.Name == taskName)
                        _found = true;
                }  
                if (_found)
                    folder.DeleteTask(taskName, 0);

                Console.WriteLine("Creating new task");
                ITaskDefinition taskDef = taskScheduler.NewTask(0);
                taskDef.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Opens notepad at the scheduled times";
                taskDef.RegistrationInfo.Author = "Monica";
                taskDef.Settings.Enabled = true;
                taskDef.Settings.Hidden = false;
                taskDef.Settings.DisallowStartIfOnBatteries = false;
                taskDef.Settings.WakeToRun = true;

                IWeeklyTrigger trigger = (IWeeklyTrigger)taskDef.Triggers.Create(_TASK_TRIGGER_TYPE2.TASK_TRIGGER_WEEKLY);
                //if (intWeekDays != 0)
                trigger.DaysOfWeek = (short)10;
                trigger.Id = "MyTimeSet";
                trigger.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.Date.AddHours(10).AddMinutes(15).AddSeconds(20).ToString(STR_DateTimeFormat.Replace(" ", "T"));

                IExecAction action = (IExecAction)taskDef.Actions.Create(_TASK_ACTION_TYPE.TASK_ACTION_EXEC);
                action.Id = "MyRun";

                string actionFile = "notepad.exe";

                action.Path = String.Concat("\"", actionFile, "\"");

                action.Arguments = String.Format("argus \"{0}\"", "argument1");

                IRegisteredTask regTask = null;

                regTask = folder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskName, taskDef, (int)_TASK_CREATION.TASK_CREATE_OR_UPDATE, null, null, _TASK_LOGON_TYPE.TASK_LOGON_NONE, "");

                Console.WriteLine("task created");                
            }
            catch (Exception e1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get when I run this program on XP machine is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class     factory for component with CLSID {0F87369F-A4E5-4CFC-BD3E-73E6154572DD} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).   at TaskScheduler.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Can someone advise where am I going wrong here.

Thanks,
Monica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Task Scheduler 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383600%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces, which this code uses, are only available starting from Windows Vista. This code will never be able to run on Windows XP.

A fallback option would be to use the [Task Scheduler 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383581%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interfaces instead, but as there is a large difference in available functionality that might not be enough. In that case there is nothing you can do, as the OS simply does not provide the services you need.

Comment: Hi Jon thanks. But since I need the program to run on XP. Is there a way to use Task Schduler 1.0. I dun mind improving the code to fit in Task Scheduler 1.0 Interface parameters so long as I am able to schedule a task. How do I import Task Scheduler 1.0 Interfaces